# Get Current Session When don't have the request object

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I'm having a problem with function calculate total user.
Inside database, I have a field login to check user logged or not. 
I have a class SessionListener to check if session is destroyed and I'll update the status of the user of session. 
The problem is when user logout by close brower and login again. I have two session one session keep current user and one keep user_logout. I check if current_user and user_logout have the same ID, I won't update status of the user. The problem is how can I check the current session to get the current_user?

Ex: 
- User A login -> a session:111 create and keep user A(status login)

- User A logout by closing browser -> session:111 wait for one minutes to be destroyed.
- User A login again -> a session:222 create and keep user A
- session:111 destroyed and update_status of user A (status logout) but actually user A not logout.

Thanks so much.

Comment: before creating a new session you can check the table if a session is there for the user.. If yes then destroy that session and create new session

Comment: so inside the database, I have to create a new  session field? Thanks